# Bind9 Permission issue, unable to sign zone

Tags: linux, ubuntu, domain-name-system, bind

fellow experts, I am new.

I am on Ubuntu 22, I am looking to enable dnssec on my side by using Bind9.

However, I don't exactly know where and how to do it.

After some trials, I have come up with something of my own (uncertain if they're correct).

(my zone file)

```
$ORIGIN zeroaccesssecuritysolutions.com.
$TTL 1D
 
@   IN  SOA ns1.zeroaccesssecuritysolutions.com. admin.zeroaccesssecuritysoluti>
        2023110101 ; Serial
        1D         ; Refresh
        2H         ; Retry
        1W         ; Expire
        1D)        ; Minimum TTL
 
@   IN  NS  ns1.zeroaccesssecuritysolutions.com.
@   IN  NS  ns2.zeroaccesssecuritysolutions.com.
 
@   IN  A   139.99.48.185
www IN  CNAME @
 
ns1 IN  A   127.0.0.1
ns2 IN  A   127.0.0.1
 
$INCLUDE /etc/bind/keys/Kzeroaccesssecuritysolutions.com.+015+01626.key
```

(my named.conf.local)

```
zone "zeroaccesssecuritysolutions.com" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/zones/zeroaccesssecuritysolutions.com";
        allow-transfer { 127.0.0.1; };
        inline-signing yes;
        serial-update-method increment;
        key-directory "/etc/bind/keys";
};
```

My server is on a different hosting instead of the hosting that has registrar, and the guide that I am using is a mixture of these sites.

https://www.talkdns.com/articles/a-beginners-guide-to-dnssec-with-bind-9/
https://www.cherryservers.com/blog/how-to-install-and-configure-a-private-bind-dns-server-on-ubuntu-22-04
https://wiki.debian.org/DNSSEC%20Howto%20for%20BIND%209.9+

Now this is the latest syslog which roughly shows the error.

```
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps systemd[1]: Starting BIND Domain Name Server...
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: starting BIND 9.18.18-0ubuntu0.22.04.1-Ubuntu (Extended Support Version) <id:>
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: running on Linux x86_64 5.15.0-91-generic #101-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 14 13:30:08 UTC 2023
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: built with  '--build=x86_64-linux-gnu' '--prefix=/usr' '--includedir=${prefix}/include' '--mandir=${prefix}/share/man' '--infodir=${prefix}/share/info' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--localstatedir=/var' '--disable-option-checking' '--disable-silent-rules' '--libdir=${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' '--runstatedir=/run' '--disable-maintainer-mode' '--disable-dependency-tracking' '--libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' '--sysconfdir=/etc/bind' '--with-python=python3' '--localstatedir=/' '--enable-threads' '--enable-largefile' '--with-libtool' '--enable-shared' '--disable-static' '--with-gost=no' '--with-openssl=/usr' '--with-gssapi=yes' '--with-libidn2' '--with-json-c' '--with-lmdb=/usr' '--with-gnu-ld' '--with-maxminddb' '--with-atf=no' '--enable-ipv6' '--enable-rrl' '--enable-filter-aaaa' '--disable-native-pkcs11' 'build_alias=x86_64-linux-gnu' 'CFLAGS=-g -O2 -ffile-prefix-map=/build/bind9-Zcprjh/bind9-9.18.18=. -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -DNO_VERSION_DATE -DDIG_SIGCHASE' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -flto=auto -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now' 'CPPFLAGS=-Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2'
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: running as: named -u bind
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: compiled by GCC 11.4.0
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: compiled with OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: linked to OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: compiled with libuv version: 1.43.0
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: linked to libuv version: 1.43.0
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: compiled with libxml2 version: 2.9.13
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: linked to libxml2 version: 20913
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: compiled with json-c version: 0.15
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: linked to json-c version: 0.15
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: compiled with zlib version: 1.2.11
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: linked to zlib version: 1.2.11
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: ----------------------------------------------------
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: BIND 9 is maintained by Internet Systems Consortium,
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: Inc. (ISC), a non-profit 501(c)(3) public-benefit 
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: corporation.  Support and training for BIND 9 are 
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: available at https://www.isc.org/support
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: ----------------------------------------------------
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: adjusted limit on open files from 524288 to 1048576
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: found 2 CPUs, using 2 worker threads
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: using 2 UDP listeners per interface
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: DNSSEC algorithms: RSASHA1 NSEC3RSASHA1 RSASHA256 RSASHA512 ECDSAP256SHA256 ECDSAP384SHA384 ED25519 ED448
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: DS algorithms: SHA-1 SHA-256 SHA-384
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: HMAC algorithms: HMAC-MD5 HMAC-SHA1 HMAC-SHA224 HMAC-SHA256 HMAC-SHA384 HMAC-SHA512
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: TKEY mode 2 support (Diffie-Hellman): yes
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: TKEY mode 3 support (GSS-API): yes
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: config.c: option 'trust-anchor-telemetry' is experimental and subject to change in the future
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: loading configuration from '/etc/bind/named.conf'
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: reading built-in trust anchors from file '/etc/bind/bind.keys'
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: looking for GeoIP2 databases in '/usr/share/GeoIP'
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: using default UDP/IPv4 port range: [32768, 60999]
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: using default UDP/IPv6 port range: [32768, 60999]
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: listening on IPv4 interface lo, 127.0.0.1#53
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: listening on IPv4 interface ens33, 139.99.48.185#53
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: IPv6 socket API is incomplete; explicitly binding to each IPv6 address separately
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: listening on IPv6 interface lo, ::1#53
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: listening on IPv6 interface ens33, fe80::250:56ff:fe0a:acac%2#53
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: generating session key for dynamic DNS
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: sizing zone task pool based on 6 zones
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: none:99: 'max-cache-size 90%' - setting to 1767MB (out of 1963MB)
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: obtaining root key for view _default from '/etc/bind/bind.keys'
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: set up managed keys zone for view _default, file 'managed-keys.bind'
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 10.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 16.172.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 17.172.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 18.172.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 19.172.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 20.172.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 21.172.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 22.172.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 23.172.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 24.172.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 25.172.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 26.172.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 27.172.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 28.172.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 29.172.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 30.172.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 31.172.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 168.192.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 64.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 65.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 66.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 67.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 68.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 69.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 70.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 71.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 72.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 73.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 74.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 75.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 76.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 77.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 78.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 79.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 80.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 81.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 82.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 83.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 84.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 85.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 86.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 87.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 88.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 89.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 90.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 91.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 92.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 93.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 94.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 95.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 96.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 97.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 98.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 99.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 100.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 101.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 102.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 103.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 104.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 105.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 106.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 107.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 108.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 109.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 110.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 111.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 112.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 113.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 114.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 115.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 116.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 117.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 118.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 119.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 120.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 121.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 122.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 123.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 124.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 125.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 126.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 127.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 254.169.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 2.0.192.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 100.51.198.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 113.0.203.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 255.255.255.255.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.IP6.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.IP6.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: D.F.IP6.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 8.E.F.IP6.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 9.E.F.IP6.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: A.E.F.IP6.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: B.E.F.IP6.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: 8.B.D.0.1.0.0.2.IP6.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: EMPTY.AS112.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: automatic empty zone: HOME.ARPA
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: configuring command channel from '/etc/bind/rndc.key'
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: command channel listening on 127.0.0.1#953
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: configuring command channel from '/etc/bind/rndc.key'
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: command channel listening on ::1#953
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: managed-keys-zone: loaded serial 23
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: zone 127.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: zone 0.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: zone 255.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: zone localhost/IN: loaded serial 2
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: zone zeroaccesssecuritysolutions.com/IN (unsigned): loaded serial 2023110101
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: zone zeroaccesssecuritysolutions.com/IN (signed): loaded serial 2023110101
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: /etc/bind/zones/zeroaccesssecuritysolutions.com.jbk: create: permission denied
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: zone zeroaccesssecuritysolutions.com/IN (signed): receive_secure_serial: unexpected error
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: zone zeroaccesssecuritysolutions.com/IN (signed): sending notifies (serial 2023110101)
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: dumping master file: /etc/bind/zones/tmp-g1A3u2PMh6: open: permission denied
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: all zones loaded
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: running
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps systemd[1]: Started BIND Domain Name Server.
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: network unreachable resolving './DNSKEY/IN': 2001:503:c27::2:30#53
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: network unreachable resolving './NS/IN': 2001:503:c27::2:30#53
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: network unreachable resolving './DNSKEY/IN': 2001:7fd::1#53
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: network unreachable resolving './NS/IN': 2001:7fd::1#53
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: network unreachable resolving './DNSKEY/IN': 2001:dc3::35#53
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: network unreachable resolving './NS/IN': 2001:dc3::35#53
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: network unreachable resolving './DNSKEY/IN': 2001:500:a8::e#53
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: network unreachable resolving './NS/IN': 2001:500:a8::e#53
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: network unreachable resolving './DNSKEY/IN': 2001:500:12::d0d#53
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: network unreachable resolving './NS/IN': 2001:500:12::d0d#53
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: network unreachable resolving './DNSKEY/IN': 2001:500:2f::f#53
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: network unreachable resolving './NS/IN': 2001:500:2f::f#53
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: network unreachable resolving './DNSKEY/IN': 2001:7fe::53#53
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: network unreachable resolving './NS/IN': 2001:7fe::53#53
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: network unreachable resolving './DNSKEY/IN': 2001:500:9f::42#53
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: network unreachable resolving './NS/IN': 2001:500:9f::42#53
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: network unreachable resolving './DNSKEY/IN': 2001:503:ba3e::2:30#53
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: network unreachable resolving './NS/IN': 2001:503:ba3e::2:30#53
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: network unreachable resolving './DNSKEY/IN': 2001:500:2::c#53
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: network unreachable resolving './NS/IN': 2001:500:2::c#53
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: network unreachable resolving './DNSKEY/IN': 2001:500:2d::d#53
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: network unreachable resolving './NS/IN': 2001:500:2d::d#53
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: network unreachable resolving './DNSKEY/IN': 2001:500:1::53#53
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: network unreachable resolving './NS/IN': 2001:500:1::53#53
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: network unreachable resolving './DNSKEY/IN': 2001:500:200::b#53
Dec 22 08:07:24 chronovps named[13666]: network unreachable resolving './NS/IN': 2001:500:200::b#53
Dec 22 08:07:25 chronovps named[13666]: managed-keys-zone: Key 20326 for zone . is now trusted (acceptance timer complete)
Dec 22 08:07:25 chronovps named[13666]: resolver priming query complete: success
Dec 22 08:07:25 chronovps named[13666]: checkhints: b.root-servers.net/A (170.247.170.2) missing from hints
Dec 22 08:07:25 chronovps named[13666]: checkhints: b.root-servers.net/A (199.9.14.201) extra record in hints
Dec 22 08:07:25 chronovps named[13666]: checkhints: b.root-servers.net/AAAA (2801:1b8:10::b) missing from hints
Dec 22 08:07:25 chronovps named[13666]: checkhints: b.root-servers.net/AAAA (2001:500:200::b) extra record in hints
Dec 22 08:07:39 chronovps systemd[1]: Started Session 69 of User root.
```

I try to do dig @127.0.0.1 [www.zeroaccesssecuritysolutions.com](http://www.zeroaccesssecuritysolutions.com) and using the ns.
It seems to me they're working. The signing part is the part that gives me immense problem at the moment.

I may mess things up and I require the assistance of system and network administrators from this site. I really want to enable DNSSEC as it's another basic security measures that most people tend to ignore...

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Please  use copy-paste in your question and avoid posting paste-bin links and/or screenshots of text when posting console output / settings. Format that text  as "`code`" using [Markdown](https://serverfault.com/editing-help) and/or the formatting options in the edit menu to properly type-set your posts. That improves readability, attracts better answers and allows indexing by search engines, which may help people with similar questions. And that will allow people willing to answer your question to also copy-and-paste your settings/error messages into their answer.

Comment: The talkdns link is broken for me. It looks like you're setting up manual zone signing rather than the fully automated zone signing using dnssec-policy. As of all recent Bind versions that comes with the warning [*"Please note manual procedures are available mainly for backwards compatibility and should be used only by expert users with specific needs."*](https://bind9.readthedocs.io/en/v9.18.10/chapter5.html#manual-signing)  - IMHO that might not be the best way study DNSSEC. - I found this manual quite helpful https://www.sidn.nl/en/modern-internet-standards/dnssec-signatures-in-bind-named

Comment: These permission denied errors `/etc/bind/zones/zeroaccesssecuritysolutions.com.jbk: create: permission denied`
and `zone zeroaccesssecuritysolutions.com/IN (signed): receive_secure_serial: unexpected : dumping master file: /etc/bind/zones/tmp-g1A3u2PMh6: open: permission denied` are easily addressed by moving your zone files to location where bind is allowed to write or by changing the permissions on `/etc/bind/zones` - Bind needs to be able to write to keep the journal for dynamic updates that is also used for automatic signing

Comment: And finally - are you seeing signed DNS records when you query your name server? `dig @localhost +dnssec zeroaccesssecuritysolutions.com`

Comment: The reason why most zone files are all on localhost, is it because the registrar will point the IP back towards the IP that we give to the registrar when getting a domain? Originally, I intend to create a keypair based on ED25519 or ED448 because of they're being more widely accepted than the current algorithm and have greater security as well.

When I do dig again it has a new RRSig answer, I would want to ask, does it matter or not really to not have a signed zone file on the server? Or the current settings will be good since I can get the DS records to submit to my registrar now

Comment: AppArmor prevents writing in /etc/bind, use /var/lib/bind. You can symlink your zones directory to there. DNSSEC is now easy to set up, see here: https://securityblog.switch.ch/2020/12/01/dnssec-signing-your-domain-with-bind-9-16/comment-page-1/